# What is the way to use a java library in a React Native Project?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement an Android application by using React-Native and I am not familiar Java.

I created a basic React-Native application that has one textbox and one button. When you click the button, its adding the textbox value to a list and showing it on the screen like below.

[image: Figure 1]

Everything seems ok. What I read about react-native is, it converting javascript to native (ios, android) code. The first question where is this converted code ? I put a placeholder to the textbox and search the placeholder text in the android folder of reach-native project. But I cannot find the text anywhere in the android folder.

[image]

I run `react-native run-android` command and its working so where is the converted code that I can find the placeholder of the textbox in android project ?

Last question is I want to use a native java library to connect an specific gateway (https://github.com/calimero-project/introduction). Whats the best way to integrate it to the react-native application ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, ReactNative is NOT converting JS to native code.  Its running it on a C based Javasript interpreter.  It turn the components returned by the render function into native views-  kind of.  Some of them at least.  Others it doesn't and uses its own replacements, so it isn't a 1:1 conversion-  a piece of text may not correspond to an Android TextView.

There is a way to do a limited bridge from RN to Java to call Java libraries.  You need to create a ReactNative Java module (and would need to create a Swift/Objective-C one on the iOS side).  See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android for documentation.